# How to determine the size of my tables in the SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, table

Is there any built-in function/stored procedure/query which is helpful to retrieve information about the size of `MyTable` in the SQL Server database?

Comment: [This answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7892349/847990) has a script that is pretty simple and does not require undocumented procedure.

Comment: The answer given by AA.SC is very useful except that the msdb database identifier needs to be removed from all the DMVs in the join.
As it stands it only reports on tables in msdb itself!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For single table you can use

```
sp_spaceused MyTable
```

For all tables in a database you can use it with `sp_msforeachtable` as follwoing

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
table_name sysname ,
row_count INT,
reserved_size VARCHAR(50),
data_size VARCHAR(50),
index_size VARCHAR(50),
unused_size VARCHAR(50))
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT #temp
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''
SELECT a.table_name,
a.row_count,
COUNT(*) AS col_count,
a.data_size
FROM #temp a
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns b
ON a.table_name collate database_default
= b.table_name collate database_default
GROUP BY a.table_name, a.row_count, a.data_size
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(a.data_size, ' KB', '') AS integer) DESC
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 53):

If you don't want to write a script, you can also open the much underused 'Object Explorer Details' in SSMS (Shortcut key F7).

[image: Top Level of Object Explorer Details]

From the Top-Level, open the Tables folder to get a list of all the tables in your database.

You may need to customise the columns to see the Space Used. This can be done by right clicking on the header row and choosing the columns you wish to display.

[image: Table data size in SSMS]

There's plenty more data like this available in Object Explorer Details.

Comment: Much nicer than the t-sql approach above (which didn't work for me)

Answer (score 24):

In SSMS right click on Database, select Reports, Standard Reports, Disk Usage by Top Tables.

The report will  give you number of rows and kilobytes used per table.

Answer (score 4):

To get table size information I like to use following script

```
SELECT  sc.name + '.' + t.NAME AS TableName,  
        p.[Rows],  
        ( SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 ) / 1024 AS TotalReservedSpaceMB, -- Number of total pages * 8KB size of each page in SQL Server  
        ( SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 ) / 1024 AS UsedDataSpaceMB,  
        ( SUM(a.data_pages) * 8 ) / 1024 AS FreeUnusedSpaceMB  
FROM    msdb.sys.tables t  
        INNER JOIN msdb.sys.schemas sc ON sc.schema_id = t.schema_id  
        INNER JOIN msdb.sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id  
        INNER JOIN msdb.sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID  
                                            AND i.index_id = p.index_id  
        INNER JOIN msdb.sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id  
WHERE   t.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'  
        AND i.index_id <= 1  --- Heap\ CLUSTERED
        AND t.NAME='MYTableName' -- Replace with valid table name
GROUP BY sc.name + '.' + t.NAME,  
        i.[object_id],i.index_id, i.name, p.[Rows]  
ORDER BY ( SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 ) / 1024 DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following script that calculates the volume for each table and another result set of the total per data base

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SpaceUsed') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SpaceUsed

    CREATE TABLE #SpaceUsed 
    (
    TableName sysname ,
    [Rows] int ,
    [Reserved] varchar(20),
    [Data] varchar(20),
    [Index_Size] varchar(20),
    [Unused] varchar(20),
    [Reserved_KB] bigint,
    [Data_KB] bigint,
    [Index_Size_KB] bigint,
    [Unused_KB] bigint
    )

    DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
    SELECT @CMD +='EXEC sp_spaceused ' +  ''''+QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+''''+';'+CHAR(10)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    --PRINT @CMD

     INSERT INTO #SpaceUsed (TableName ,[Rows] , [Reserved], [Data] , [Index_Size] , [Unused] )
     EXEC sp_executesql @CMD



     UPDATE #SpaceUsed 
     SET [Reserved_KB] = CONVERT(BIGINT,RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE([Reserved] , ' KB', '')))),
         [Data_KB] = CONVERT(BIGINT,RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE([Data] , ' KB', '')))),
         [Index_Size_KB]= CONVERT(BIGINT,RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE([Index_Size] , ' KB', '')))),
         [Unused_KB]= CONVERT(BIGINT,RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE([Unused] , ' KB', ''))))


     SELECT TableName, [Rows], Reserved_KB , Data_KB , Index_Size_KB , Unused_KB ,  Data_KB / 1024.0 Data_MB , Data_KB / 1024.0 / 1024.0 Data_GB
     FROM #SpaceUsed
     ORDER BY Data_KB DESC 

     SELECT SUM(Reserved_KB) Reserved_KB , SUM(Data_KB) Data_KB, SUM(Index_Size_KB) Index_Size_KB , SUM(Unused_KB) Unused_KB ,SUM(Data_KB / 1024.0) Data_MB , SUM(Data_KB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) Data_GB
     FROM #SpaceUsed

     DROP TABLE #SpaceUsed
```

Comment: damn, this script is really good, thanks... 
I tested it on Azure SQL and works...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at sys.dm_db_partition_stats (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187737.aspx).

There are some sample queries at that link and also at [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cindygross/dmv-series-sys-dm_db_partition_stats)

You can modify to suit your needs i.e. filter in/out non-clustered indexes. Multiply page count by 8 to get size in KB, then divide by 2^10 (=1024) to convert to MB if required.

sp_spaceused (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) will also give table size information.

Answer (score 1):

Go to to database then right click and click on reports then standard reports then disk usage by table. This will give you all the ta les in that database and thier records, data, indexes etc